# How is 8086 processor 1MB when 2^20 bits is not 1MB its 1Mb?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

How can 8086 microprocessor have 1 Mega Byte memory when it can address upto 2^20 bits which are equal to 1 Mega Bits not 1 Mega Bytes.

Comment: Addressing is using bytes. You can't address individual bits in 8086.

Comment: Did you read somewhere that it addresses up to 2^20 *bits* rather than *bytes*?

Comment: Please explain with example i am still not getting it.

Comment: @Jester Except with bt, bts, btr, and btc. only from the 80386 on though.

Comment: @fuz of course 8086 doesn't have those. The x86 cpus that do have those, can address more than 1MB ;)

Comment: The address is *using* 20 bits, but each memory address refers to a byte.

Comment: @ThomasJager: all it needs is an answer with positive score to be a valid dup target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] it can address upto 2^20 bits [...]

No, it can address 2<sup>20</sup> *locations*. Each location is one byte, which means that 1 mebibyte is addressable.